# 304 Not modified response when serving files through PHP

Tags: php, caching

I have a PHP file serving image files. I looks like this:

```
$dir = 'directory/containing/files';
$file = getFileInfoFromDatabase(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'article'));

header("Content-Type: $file->type; name=\"$file->filename\"");
header("Name: \"$file->filename\"");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"$file->filename\"");
header("Content-Length: $file->size");

die(readfile($dir.'/'.$file->id));
```

An url calling this file looks like this: `www.example.com/article/image.php?article=4`. `4` is the id of the article, which is sent to the database to get information stored there about the image file associated with that article.

This works well. When loading the url, I get the image and some response headers looking like this:

```
Cache-Control:private, max-age=10800, pre-check=10800
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition:inline; filename="filename.jpg"
Content-Length:37308
Content-Type:image/jpeg; name="filename.jpg"
Date:Wed, 30 Sep 2015 08:42:26 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=75
Last-Modified:Wed, 30 Sep 2015 08:32:19 GMT
Name:"filename.jpg"
Server:Apache
```

The next time I try loading the url, the request contains the following header:

```
If-Modified-Since:Wed, 30 Sep 2015 08:32:19 GMT
```

And I get a `304 Not Modified` response, which is fine.

However, if I update the database to point to a different file, I get the same `304 Not Modified` response! I have to modify the php file serving the image file to get the new version of the image file.

How can I solve this? Do I have to turn off caching for this file? Or can I change the `Last-Modified` header to be that of the image file instead of the php file in some way?

Comment: **dont use die()** `readfile()` does not even need an echo it writes directly to the output buffer. Rather use an `exit;` after the `readfile()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the modification time of the changed file, you can change the `last_modified` header if the request `If-Modified-Since` is older.